# Need to give users more feedback when presented with the '...appears subjective...' warning.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions

The *Ask Question* page need to give users more info/feedback when the '*Question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed*'' warning is shown.

I was shown this warning while asking [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/best-way-to-accept-user-input-of-multiple-numbers) and it is frustrating to not be given any advice on how to improve the style/wording.

I am a reasonably experienced StackOverflow user and am well aware of the [whole subjective 
  argument](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) so it was easy enough for me to sort out.

But if an inexperienced user got this, they wouldn't have a clue what it meant or how they were supposed to fix it.  All it really needs is a link to a relevant page (see link above maybe) explaining how to 'unsubjectify' your question.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you're mentioning this on the UI StackExchange meta, I think it's worth noting that we currently don't have the same opinion about subjective questions. In UI, it's almost impossible *not* to ask a subjective question. So in terms of how it should work here ideally, I'd think about removing the subjective warning and instead adding a warning when you seem to be asking a list question. List questions can be inferred from words like "best", in your example.

But yes, the feedback should be more clear.

Comment: As users (uh, me) move between various SE sites, the different thresholds/standards/opinions regarding subjective questions can be confusing.  While I absolutely get the need for differing standards between sites/communities, I think the info explaining each site's standards should be more accessible, especially for new users.   That said, UI.SE _is_ still in beta so this is just part of the definition process.

Comment: It's still in beta, but what you're suggesting is also a network-wide problem. Not sure posting the suggestion here on UI meta will reach the right people, but not sure where else to do it. Perhaps on StackOverflow meta, which has a lot more traffic?

Answer (score 3):

I agree; I turned off the subjective warning indicator for UI.

Comment: Thanks, good decision. Rahul hit the nail on the head with his answer. And as per his comment, probably not a bad idea to mirgrate this to meta.SO as it is a network wide problem. The only problem I can see is that each SE site may need a different solution, as indicated by the solution used here.

Comment: And how does it feel to have 101 rep again?  Been a while huh?  ; )

Comment: I wish I could post images of dancing bananas in comments. ... But I guess it's a good thing we can't.